# What type of PK data you will get from CRF and central Labs?

Tags: sas, statsmodels

Clinical SAS PK data related question

Comment: This isn't really a SO type question, you can try asking on communities.sas.com but you'll need to provide more details there as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are coding site for coders. [plese consult help section on how to formulate your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)